# X "has that" instead of X "can do that"

Tags: phrases, colloquialisms

I've been encountering this more often lately. Two examples:

1. After witnessing an impressive athletic display (a spinning reverse dunk), the announcer says "Ohh I didn't know he **had** that."
2. Two radio DJs talking about how they're from the Bronx so they will always love Jennifer Lopez, even though she's sell-out: "Even when she said the N-word in that one song... she **gets** that."

Both struck me as unexpected and delightful. And more interesting than what I would have said ("I didn't know he could do that", and "she's allowed to do that").

My question is, has anyone encountered this before? What is the origin for this kind of construction? Is it standard in any other languages?

Answer (score 1):

He/she *gets* that (they get that) is common and has been in usage for a long time. It's simply idiomatic usage.

[get](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+to) 9.a. To gain or have understanding of: *Do you get this question?*

> This teacher is rockin because he *gets that you have an actual life* outside of his class and he almost encourages it! (rate my professor.com)

*He **has** that* is just a rephrasing of *he* **has** *that in him*:

> ... Mr Scott has already exhibited in our K'iinburgh exhibitions, to convince us that **he has that in him** which, if turned to a proper use, will yet lead to great things. (1831)

Comment: Is 'K'iinburgh' for *Edinburgh* a Google OCR failure, or  editorial unfamiliarity?